# api proxy server not parsing data back to user CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am trying to access an api but when I access it in the browser, I get a CORS error. To get around this problem I set up an api proxy server. When this proxy gets a html request it connects to the browser blocked api and pulls the data needed. I think there is a problem on the proxy server where it is also blocking CORS and that needs to be changed, I’m not so sure. When I call the proxy api it gets the data from the browser blocked api and logs it to the console but does not push it to the browser because of the error below.

1.How do I correct this error “Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing”
2.Should I be doing this a different way?

**Error**
[image: error 1]

**Data being logged on the server**
[image: server pulling data]

**Server routing code - app.js**

```
  const apiCallFromRequest = require('./Request')
    const apiCallFromNode = require('./NodeJsCall')
    const apiCallFromTEST = require('./test.js')


    const http = require('http')


    http.createServer((req, res) => {


             if(req.url === "/test"){
            let start_time = new Date().getTime();
            apiCallFromTEST.callApi(function(response){
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                res.write(JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log(response);
                console.log("Request API Requested");
                console.log('API Test Time:', new Date().getTime() - start_time, 'ms');
                res.end();
            });
```

API proxy rought code -test.js

```
var rp = require('request-promise');



const callExternalApiUsingRequest = (callback) => {
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://app.invoiceninja.com/api/v1/products',
        headers: {
            'X-Ninja-Token': 'APIKEY'
        },
        json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
    };
    rp(options)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return callback(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // API call failed...
        });
}
module.exports.callApi = callExternalApiUsingRequest;
```

website side - Just a basic fetch request

> ```
> function gotProductData(){
>
>   fetch('http://localhost:3000/test')
>   .then(function(response) {
>     return response.json();
>   })
>   .then(function(myJson) {
>     console.log(myJson);
>   });
> ```

Comment: You'll have to enable cors. [this](https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node) should help you

Comment: i dont think im doing right. the server does not load when i try this method.

Comment: Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: Thank you for your support, i managed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install "**cors**" package (**npm install cors**) and import to app.js :

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

Run that above routes:

```
app.use(cors())
```

More details:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#installation

Comment: im not to sure where i hve to put the app.user(cors()). could you please explain?

Comment: Add that under     const http = require('http')

Comment: `const apiCallFromRequest = require('./Request')
const apiCallFromNode = require('./NodeJsCall')
const apiCallFromTEST = require('./test.js')
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()


http = require('http')

app.use(cors())

http.createServer((req, res) => { `

This is what i have done (Above) and this is the error i get when loading the server (Bellow).
prntscr.com/ot7rk5

Comment: The error happens, because you do not use express as a middleware. That may be better to integrate that into your app. Installation documentation:
https://expressjs.com/